# javascript, remove parameters from youtube link, in string

Tags: javascript, youtube

hi I have a string that contains several youtube links

```
test test test
https://youtu.be/G7KNmW9a75Y?list=PL08MW4hWrm0I5BMN-Z_r8dqRdNTyuyRaD
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JlOZR5OwS-8&list=PL08MW4hWrm0I5BMN-Z_r8dqRdNTyuyRaD&index=4
test test test
```

it is possible to clean youtube links from their parameters, and make them become;
https://youtu.be/G7KNmW9a75Y
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JlOZR5OwS-8

complete with the entire string

```
test test test
https://youtu.be/G7KNmW9a75Y
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JlOZR5OwS-8
test test test
```

many thanks to whoever offers the solution

i used this

```
'test test test  youtu.be/G7KNmW9a75Y?list=PL08MW4hWrm0I5BMN-Z_r8dqRdNTyuyRaD  youtube.com/watch?v=JlOZR5OwS-8&list=PL08MW4hWrm0I5BMN-Z_r8dqRdNTyuyRaD&index=4 test test test'.replace(/<[^>]*>?/gm, '').replace('https:&#47;/'+videoid[0], "");
```

but it doesn't extract the complete link in order to use replace, and delete it from the text

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

generally to get "https://youtu.be/G7KNmW9a75Y" out of "https://youtu.be/G7KNmW9a75Y?list=PL08MW4hWrm0I5BMN-Z_r8dqRdNTyuyRaD" you need to use `new URL()`:

`let u = new URL('https://youtu.be/G7KNmW9a75Y?list=PL08MW4hWrm0I5BMN-Z_r8dqRdNTyuyRaD')`
`${u.origin}${u.pathname}` // "https://youtu.be/G7KNmW9a75Y" <-- your answer

Full code:

```
  const myStr =
        "test test test https://youtu.be/G7KNmW9a75Y?list=PL08MW4hWrm0I5BMN-Z_r8dqRdNTyuyRaD https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JlOZR5OwS-8&list=PL08MW4hWrm0I5BMN-Z_r8dqRdNTyuyRaD&index=4 test test test";

      const result = myStr
        .split(" ")
        .map((str) => {
          if (str.match(/\bhttps?:\/\/\S+/gi)) {
            let u = new URL(
              "https://youtu.be/G7KNmW9a75Y?list=PL08MW4hWrm0I5BMN-Z_r8dqRdNTyuyRaD"
            );
            return `${u.origin}${u.pathname}`;
          }

          return str;
        })
        .join("\r\n");

      console.log("result", result); // I noticed that the result of the `map()` fn should be stored in variable otherwise strings won't be placed in new lines
```